# The thickness of my model is not always accurate. How do I solve this?

Tags: z-axis, nozzle, simplify3d

After replacing the nozzle on my Creatbot F430 printer, I auto-leveled the bed and initiated a test print - a simple square with a 2 mm thickness. However, I observed that the thickness of the printed model is inconsistent, varying between 1.5 mm and 1.7 mm. I'm wondering the Z-Offset is affecting this, or I shouldn't really worry about 0.3 mm / 0.5 mm difference.

Nozzle Size is 0.4 mm

[image: Printer Setting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the Z offset needs to be redone each time a nozzle is removed even if you re install the same size.

Another thing to verify is to ensure the slicer is actually set with a 0.4mm nozzle